# JSch ChannelExec time out after 15 minutes

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am running a command on remote server using JSch's `ChannelExec`. My script usually takes more than 15 minutes to run. But the channel is getting closed after 15 minutes and the exit status stays equal to -1.

I have even tried to wait until the channel is closed. But `channelExec.isClosed()` returns `true` after 15 minutes.

I think I need to set timeout configuration somewhere but I couldn't figure it out. Setting `Session.setTimeout()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

channel also closes after a certain maximmum time limit.
to keep the channel open indefinitely use channel.connect(0).
Even though the specification says it to run indefinitely yet even this will have a upper limit or else OS itself will timeoue the process